# How to create a report in Jira of all the hours I've worked in a week

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, time-tracking

We use Jira ( plain jira, no greenhopper ) for project/task management and a separate system for time tracking.

How can I run a report to extract all the hours I have worked in the last week?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using a web-based project management tool, not an application used primarily by programmers or an API.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not sure that I agree in this case - this still seems like a tool used primarily by programmers. This seems like it's primarily a task that someone actually working on a project (not just a project manager) would want to perform.

Comment: @EJoshuaS It is no different than creating a flowchart in Microsoft Word as part of your software documentation. That's not on-topic here, either. Jira isn't even a tool "primarily used for programming", as the close reason states is the exception. A PM or accountant would be the ones counting up hours worked.

Comment: @CodyGray But the OP says that they want *their* hours for their own personal use, which is different than what a PM or accountant would do. I'm still not convinced that this is a "general computing" question - I use it constantly as a developer (including for strictly programming-related tasks like dev testing).

Comment: Have you tried Jira Assistant from https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1221570/jassistant. It is free, open source and easy to configure. No special permissions in Jira is required to install and configure.

You can use this addon for Worklog / Timesheet report, Sprint report, and custom report  generation with grouping. Additionally you can also use it to bulk import worklog / issues and much more.

[Disclaimer] I am the developer of this browser extension.

Answer (score 22):

You can create a custom filter with a custom search query:

```
project = "My project" and timeSpent is not null and updated > startOfWeek("-1") and assignee was CurrentUser()
```

More information on JQL is here - https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching#AdvancedSearching-Updated

Comment: But how does this filter result in a timesheet?

Comment: You need to use a plugin like Tempo to get a timesheet view.

Comment: Only works if you are the only user to log work on that item, if multiple users log work it counts the entire time spent to be for the final assignee

Answer (score 6):

### Work already completed

One way would be to install the [timesheet plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/jira-timesheet-plugin) which generates a tablular breakdown of time logged against projects, tasks and lets you export the information in Excel.

I've install the plugin quickly to get an idea of how well it works;

[image: Timesheet report]

I think this is what you're looking for when producing retrospective time data.

### Remaining Work

You can make use of the [User Workload](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/User+Workload+Report) report which..

> displays useful time tracking information on issues assigned to a
>   particular user. It shows the number of unresolved issues assigned to
>   the specified user, and the workload remaining, on a per-project
>   basis.

To create a report, you need to view (any) Project page, then select "User Workload Report" from the "Reports" link on the top right of the Summary screen. The [JIRA Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/User+Workload+Report) has more instructions.

As an example, the report generated for myself is as follows;

[image]

Comment: Why we need to pay extra for such a basic feature? Isn't paying for Jira enough?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try our plugin [Intelligent Reports](http://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.clariostechnology.intelligentreports).  It lets you design the output format you want in Microsoft Word, and fill in the data using simple point and click rules, which allow you to filter, sort, etc. on all attributes of logged time.

It even comes with two timesheet example reports, a project timesheet and a cross-project timesheet.  These should be easily adaptable to what you need.

As a quick note, JQL alone cannot filter logged time data completely, as it only returns issues.  For instance, in the query given in the other answer, it will miss any work you may have logged against an issue that is assigned to someone else.  Intelligent Reports lets you start with a JQL query, but further refine it using the attributes of the logged time directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "JIRA Timesheet Reports and Gadget" for that, it generates beautifully structured report with wide range of configuration options. 
It costs money, BUT it's only for extra functionality like "Working Days" or "Subscriptions". Main timesheet report functionality is free. 
It's preinstalled for OnDemand or you can install it for your hosted instance. You can use it without a licence as I described.

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/jira-timesheet-reports-and-gadgets-removal-from-jira-cloud-792504481.html: "As of 6 May 2016, the JIRA Timesheet Reports and Gadgets plugin has been removed from JIRA Cloud."